# jigsaw puzzle carrier

Tags: air-travel, luggage

I have a 1000 piece puzzle I want to put in my checked bag.  It is a roll pack with an inflatable part that must stay inflated to roll the puzzle and keep it in place.  Can I put this in my checked bag with the inflated roll?

Comment: Can you provide an image of what you are describing? What and where are you flying? But, if something is inflated, pressurised, I'd say your chances are small.

Comment: @MastaBaba Most likely something like [this](https://www.amazon.com/Puzzle-Roll-Mat-Inflatable-Playground/dp/B07PPBDW2H)

Comment: Unless there are specified limits on altitude, and altitude change, I suggest asking the manufacturer. The is a risk that if it is inflated enough to support the puzzle at ground level it may be over-inflated at the equivalent of a few thousand feet above sea level.

Answer (score 2):

The inflatable part, even if it works above 8,000 feet, may not be designed for the rapid drop in surrounding pressure in the cargo hold of an aircraft. It could be damaged by over-inflation.

To be on the safe side, I suggest modifying your puzzle pack. Get a cardboard tube at least as wide as the felt. Roll it up around the tube from the free end of the felt, and deflate the inflatable tube. Secure with bungee cords or in any other convenient way.

Comment: What rapid drop in surrounding pressure? The cargo hold is at the same pressure as the passenger cabin.

Comment: Most aircraft are only pressurized to about 6000 to 8000 feet above sea level. If the OP takes off from an airport at e.g. 1000 feet above sea level there will be a drop in pressure equivalent to several thousand feet increase in altitude. Of course, for all I know the OP may be flying from La Paz, Bolivia and pressure will increase during climb-out, squeezing the puzzle holder bag from the outside.